# Toggle button not displayed when using md-switch angular material directive

Tags: angularjs

// i have created switchDemo1 module and controller SwitchDemoCtrl.
   // scope data object is defined with initial value.

```
angular.module('switchDemo1', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('SwitchDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    cb1: true,
    cb4: true,
    cb5: false
  };

// code in view
    <md-switch ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Switch 1">
            Switch 1: {{ data.cb1 }}
    </md-switch>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<body ng-controller="SwitchDemoCtrl" layout="row" layout-fill layout-align="space-around center">
  <md-switch ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Switch 1">
    Switch 1: {{ data.cb1 }}
  </md-switch>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3qAO0e?p=preview)**

Comment: Toogle button is not displayed only 'Switch 1: true' text display on page.

Comment: @devverma no it displays, check the demo

Comment: Yes,it occur only on my side.Is it require jquery?

Comment: @devverma you got it sorted?

Comment: Yes,Actually i missed to include DI 'ngMaterial' my code.

Comment: there is a tick mark on the left of answer , to mark it answer click it